# Deactivating a filter applied to a card in POWER BI

Tags: filter, powerbi

```
Rank Turnover = 
RANKX(
    ALL(Regions[Region]),
    CALCULATE([Sales Total],KEEPFILTERS(Sales[Currency]="EUR"))
)
```

Hi everyone, got stuck with this one for the second day in a row. There are 3 tables in a dataset (Regions, Sales and Currency). Regions and Currency are filtering out the Dashboard when applied. My Intention is to have Total Sales in a Card for EUR only for a Chosen in a Region Filter Country. Everything works fine, but whenever I choose "LC" (Local Currency) in Currency Filter, the numbers Change - I Need to overcome that. Changing LC in that Filter should not affect Total Sales, they have to still be done in EUR.

Any help will be appreciated,

Thank you

Comment: Rank Function Shows a rank for the Country based on sales

Comment: Where you wants to show the SUM of EUR? in a CARD? or in each row of a tabale visual?

Answer (score 0):

```
Rank Sales EUR = 
RANKX(
ALL(Regions[Region]),
CALCULATETABLE(
    {[Sales Total]},
    TREATAS({"EUR"}, 'Dashboard Currency'[Currency]),FILTER(Dates, Dates[Year]=MAX([Year]))))
```

Here is the answer. Thank you all for support